# How do I pull the correct image URL from this Wikipedia table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I built a scraper to pull all the information out of a Wikipedia table and upload it to my database. All was good until I realized I was pulling the wrong URL on images, and I wanted the actual image URL "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/38/Baconbutty.jpg" and not the "/wiki/File:Baconbutty.jpg" it was apt to give me. Here is my code so far:

```
def initialize
  @url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sandwiches"
  @nodes = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url))  
end

def summary

  sammich_data = @nodes

  sammiches = sammich_data.css('div.mw-content-ltr table.wikitable tr') 
    sammich_data.search('sup').remove

    sammich_hashes = sammiches.map {|x| 

      if content = x.css('td')[0]
        name = content.text
      end
      if content = x.css('td a.image').map {|link| link ['href']}
        image =content[0]
      end
      if content = x.css('td')[2]
        origin = content.text
      end
      if content = x.css('td')[3]
        description =content.text
      end
```

My issue is with this line:

```
if content = x.css('td a.image').map {|link| link ['href']}
            image =content[0]
```

If I go to `td a.image img`, it just gives me a `null` entry.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're also scraping Wikipedia instead of using its API, which makes life harder for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it (if I was to scrape Wikipedia, which I wouldn't because they do have an API for this stuff):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'pp'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sandwiches"))  

sammich_hashes = doc.css('table.wikitable tr').map { |tr| 
  name, image, origin, description = tr.css('td,th')
  name, origin, description = [name, origin, description].map{ |n| n && n.text ? n.text : nil }
  image = image.at('img')['src'] rescue nil

  {
    name: name,
    origin: origin,
    description: description,
    image: image
  }
}

pp sammich_hashes
```

Which outputs:

```
[
  {:name=>"Name", :origin=>"Origin", :description=>"Description", :image=>nil},
  {
    :name=>"Bacon",
    :origin=>"United Kingdom",
    :description=>"Often served with ketchup or brown sauce",
    :image=>"//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/38/Baconbutty.jpg/120px-Baconbutty.jpg"
  },
  ... [lots removed] ...
{
    :name=>"Zapiekanka",
    :origin=>"Poland",
    :description=>"A halved baguette or other bread usually topped with mushrooms and cheese, ham or other meats, and vegetables",
    :image=>"//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/12/Zapiekanka_3..jpg/120px-Zapiekanka_3..jpg"
  }
]
```

If an image isn't available, the field will be set to `nil` in the returned hashes.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize about the API, but honestly this was still a good lesson.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `srcset` attribute of the `img`element, split it and keep one of the available resized images.

```
if content = x.at_css('td a.image img')
  image =content['srcset'].split(' 1.5x,').first
```